# Select 2 buttons on page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cordova

I ran into a very weird issue with my page. I am editing transactions and on the page I can save the changes or delete the item. When the internet is very slow, a user can select the delete button, then press the save button before the page changes. This causes certain variables not to be set and crashes the server.

Here is the page, pretty simple.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="banner">Changes</div>
<div>
    <label class="item">Date</label><br>
    <input ng-model = "trans.mDate" type="datetime-local" required>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="item">What</label><br>
    <input ng-model = "trans.mDescr" type="text" required>
</div>
<div style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(105,240,174,.5);margin-bottom: 20px;width: 90%;">
   <input ng-model="trans.m_type" id="Credit" value="Credit" type="radio" style="background:#00E676;width:5%;"/>
   <label for="Credit" style="color: #00E676;width:25%">Credit</label>
   <input ng-model="trans.m_type" id="Debit" value="Debit" type="radio" style="background:#FF1744;width:5%;"/>
   <label for="Debit" style="color: #00E676;">Debit</label>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="item">How Much</label><br>
    <input ng-model = "trans.mAmt" type="number" required>
</div>
<button type="button" class="third-btn" ng-click="save(trans)">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="third-btn third-delete-btn" ng-click="delete(trans)">Delete</button>
<button type="button" class="third-btn third-cancel-btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
```

I know that the edit button is being selected, because that is the only way it could get into that route.

```
Mongoose: m_trans.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("*************") }) { fields: undefined }  
Mongoose: m_trans.remove({ _id: ObjectId("*************") }) {}  
172.1.1.1 - - [30/Mar/2016:20:46:56 +0000] "DELETE /trans/**************      HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_4 like Mac OS X)     AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12H143 (391228672)"
 Mongoose: m_trans.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("*************") }) {   fields: undefined }  
 Wed Mar 30 2016 20:47:06 GMT+0000 (UTC): Node server stopped.

/app/app/routes.js:786
         trans.mID = req.body.mID
               ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'mID' of null

   app.put('/trans/:id',
  isLoggedIn,
  function (req, res){
  return models.TransModel.findById(req.params.id, function (err, trans) {
     trans.mID = req.body.mID;
     trans.mDate = req.body.mDate;
     trans.mType = req.body.mType;
     trans.mDescr = req.body.mDescr;
     trans.mAmt = req.body.mAmt;
     return trans.save(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
           console.log("updated");
        } else {
           console.log(err);
        }
        return res.send(JSON.stringify(trans));
     });
  });
```

});

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disable the buttons when pressed until you get a response (if ajax) or the page refreshes

Comment: You can use ng-disabled and temporally disable the button, then you re-enable once you have the result of the first request

Comment: Apart from disabling buttons, you can also consider having some kind of a wait dialog with a spinner telling the user that the application is processing the request

Answer (score 0):

You should disable all other buttons when you request for any operation and after request response you should enable again all buttons. Also you can show a busy icon when you make a request until got any response.

You can achieve simply using `ng-disable`  and a **flag** to set `request` made or `request` complete.

For example:

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="request" ng-click="save()" >Save</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="request" ng-click="delete()" >Delete</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="request" ng-click="cancel()" >Cancel</button>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.request = false; // initially set request false

   $scope.save = function() {
     $scope.request = true; // set true when clicked on save button

     $timeout(function() {
       $scope.request = false;  // after request complete set false again
     },1000); // wait 1 second after made request. 

   };
```

See [PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GfAqwJaC3177AaDAH8JN?p=preview)